# Invoke Oracle View using Java

Tags: java, view, oracle10g

I have a View in Oracle. I need to access the data from java. How could I do it?

I have tried the following query:

```
select DEBIT_CARD_PAN 
from pbxhbl.VIEW_VISION_CARD_NUMBER 
where FRANCHISE_ID = '43215'
```

If I run this query directly from the Oracle then it gives the result but if I invoke it from my Java code then it throws the following error:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got it.
i didn't grant the the permission to the user

Comment: @LutzHorn IMO this is an answer to the question - not a comment or part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the same user from both contexts?
If not, Do you have the correct privileges to view that particular view on the user you connect with in you application?

Answer (score 0):

A few Reasons could be the cause of this. Make sure that the Java Application Is connecting to the Oracle database using the user `pbxhbl`. if Not make sure the user the Application is using to connect has select rights on the View. Otherwise if these are not the case you should closely check your spelling.